# I am trying to slice: however we haven't learned it yet

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to take two random ints, and then slice the corresponding numbered things out of the list, however I am unsure as what I should do. it says the colon in [r1:r2] is not correct.

```
from random import* 

#2

z=['cats','dogs','soccer','weather','whale','tennis']

def slicer(ls):
    r1=randrange(0,5)
    r2=randrange(0,5)
    for x in ls:
        [r1:r2]
    return('The slice from '+str(r1)+' to '+str(r2)+' is: ' + ls)

print(slicer(z))
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Are you trying to take to random numbers and print slice of every element of the list?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to slice nothing. [r1:r2] isn't valid python syntax.

What I think you're trying to do is something like:

```
sliced = ls[r1:r2]
```

but even THAT is unlikely to do what you want as the second number in the slice needs to be HIGHER.

A more correct approach to what you seem to be trying to do (but I'm not a mindreader)

```
r1 = randrange(0,len(ls)-1)
r2 = randrange(0,len(ls)-r1-1) #Number of items to slice, -1
slice = ls[r1:r1+r2]
```

This will return a subsection of the list, at least 1 item long

Answer (score 0):

That's because in order to slice, you need a list (or sequence like object) to take the slice from.

What you probably meant to do was just `return ls[r1:r2]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it

```
from random import* 

z=['cats','dogs','soccer','weather','whale','tennis']

def slicer(ls):
    r1=randrange(0,5)
    r2=randrange(0,5)

    if (r1<r2):
        return('The slice from '+str(r1)+' to '+str(r2)+' is: ' + str(ls[r1:r2]))
    else:
        return('The slice from '+str(r2)+' to '+str(r1)+' is: ' + str(ls[r2:r1]))
print(slicer(z))
```

Comment: never mind this is still wrong, it will not return the sliced list at the end

Comment: If `r2 > r1` the slice may be empty. If you want to reverse the slice you should do `ls[r1:r2:-1]` in that case.